# How do I properly do key trapping in C?

Tags: c, error-handling, keypress

I've been trying to figure out how to prevent an unwanted input from appearing when a user is inputting. My code is a bit weird because when the user is presses backspace the characters are still on the screen when they should be deleted.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
    int main(void)
    {
        char ch;
        while(1){
           ch=getch();
           if(isalpha(ch)){
              putchar(ch);
           }
           else if(ch=='\b'){
              putchar('\b');
           }
           else if(ch=='\n'||ch==EOF)
              break;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You could maintain the whole line in an array and refresh the entire line on screen when the user presses a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
else if(ch=='\b'){
   putchar('\b');
   putchar(' ');
   putchar('\b');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it all in a buffer...

```
int main()
{
    char    c;
    char    input[2] = "X";
    char    line[1000] = "";

    for (;;) {
        input[0] = c = getchar();
        if (isalpha(c)) {
            strcat(line, input); // Not safe for production
            putchar('\f'); // Go back to the start of line
            fputs(line, stdout); // Print the line and NO newline
        }
        else if (c == '\n' || c == EOF) {
            puts(""); // newline
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("You entered >%s<\n", line);
}
```

Comment: I tried your code out and it worked.. I'm just wondering why my code doesn't break whenever I hit enter..

Comment: I use getchar() instead of getch().  I don't know what getch() returns for newline.  You could print out the ascii value of what you get.

Comment: I would if I could but I don't have 15 reputation yet

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example how to handle multi-char keys:

```
while (_kbhit())
{
    int key = _getch(); // Get key
    if (key == 0 || key == 224)
    {
        key = 256 + _getch(); // Handle multi-char keys
    }
//handle imputs:
    if      (key == 256+75) ... // BTN_LEFT
    else if (key == 256+77) ... // BTN_RIGHT
    else if (key == 256+72) ... // BTN_UP
    else if (key == 256+80) ... // BTN_DOWN
    else if (key == 27)     ... // BTN_ESC
    else if (key == 'B')    ...
}
```

I don't know how to delete a single char on screen, but you can clear that line and rewrite characters without the last one